# Dynamic data source of the view rendering is not working in sitecore 8.2

Tags: presentation, datasource

I use sitecore 8.2 and I can't understand the purpose of the "Data source" field on the "View rendering" item.

It seems that datasource works only when I statically specify it inside the cshtml file:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("/sitecore/layout/renderings/jobs/footercontent", new {DataSource = "/sitecore/content/Global/Footer"})
```

But if I define the datasource in the "Data source" filed of the view rendering then it stops working.

[image]

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("/sitecore/layout/renderings/jobs/footercontent")
```

From your experience, why could it happen?
Shouldn't it work when I dynamically bind the datasource in the "Content Editor"?

Answer (score 5):

When you specify the datasource in the `Data Source` field of the Rendering item definition, you effectively set the "default datasource" for that component.

If you do not specify the `Data Source` in **Control Properties** in *Experience Editor* mode (or **Presentation Details** in *Content Editor*) then the datasource you specified on the Rendering item definition will be used.

It's also worth noting that if you set the datasource on the Rendering item then the `Select the Associated Content` dialog [will not appear when you add a component to a page](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/03/17/prompt-user-to-selectcreate-datasource-item-when-inserting-rendering-via-page-editor/).

But setting the "default datasource" this way is the same whether you dynamically or statically bind your components.

Since your static binding is pointing to a Sitecore Rendering definition item, it should use this datasource. It works as expected (and like in your example) in Sitecore 8.1 Update-3 but this looks like a bug in Sitecore 8.2, or at least a breaking change. I would raise a ticket with Sitecore Support and have them investigate/fix this.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using next code:

```
       @Html.Sitecore().Rendering("{240A3624-8600-4A7B-8C07-5846A673F1F0}", new
                           {
                               DataSource = "{7CB5F3A9-F301-44C0-AB73-7A19837DA01C}"
                           })
```

First time is checking if the Rendering has a definition item and it set a datasource if it has a definition item.
  After it verifies if has a Parameter in the .cshtml and if exist then it override the definition item.
  Bellow code is used when you use .Rendering helper method

```
  protected virtual Rendering GetRendering(string renderingType, object parameters, params string[] defaultValues)
    {
        Rendering rendering = new Rendering();
        rendering.RenderingType = renderingType;
        for (int i = 0; i < defaultValues.Length - 1; i += 2)
        {
            rendering[defaultValues[i]] = defaultValues[i + 1];
        }
        if (rendering.RenderingItem != null)
        {
            Item innerItem = rendering.RenderingItem.InnerItem;
            this.CopyPropertyFromDefinitionItem(rendering, innerItem, "Cacheable");
            this.CopyPropertyFromDefinitionItem(rendering, innerItem, "Cache_Timeout");
            this.CopyPropertyFromDefinitionItem(rendering, innerItem, "Cache_VaryByData");
            this.CopyPropertyFromDefinitionItem(rendering, innerItem, "Cache_VaryByDevice");
            this.CopyPropertyFromDefinitionItem(rendering, innerItem, "Cache_VaryByLogin");
            this.CopyPropertyFromDefinitionItem(rendering, innerItem, "CacheKey");
            this.CopyPropertyFromDefinitionItem(rendering, innerItem, "Cache_VaryByParameters");
            this.CopyPropertyFromDefinitionItem(rendering, innerItem, "Cache_VaryByQueryString");
            this.CopyPropertyFromDefinitionItem(rendering, innerItem, "Cache_VaryByUser");
            this.CopyPropertyFromDefinitionItem(rendering, innerItem, "DataSource");
            this.CopyPropertyFromDefinitionItem(rendering, innerItem, "Model");
        }
        if (parameters != null)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> properties = TypeHelper.GetProperties(parameters);
            properties.Each(delegate(KeyValuePair<string, object> pair)
            {
                rendering.Properties[pair.Key] = pair.Value.ValueOrDefault((object o) => o.ToString());
            });
        }
        return rendering;
    }
```

I tried on Sitecore 8.2.1 and it works as expected for me.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is a bug - rename the field in the definition item of the component as Datasource (i.e. remove the space) and it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

When your view rendering is part of your item's presentation then I don't think so you want to explicitly mention data source in cshtml file.

You might be aware that request could follow in below sequence when view rendering is concerned

(After HttpRequstPipeline) --> sitecore item (with presentation details) --> sitecore's view rendering --> MVC area 's view rendering.

Hope it clarifies :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting this on the view rendering I'm not sure Sitecore will pick that up by default. I think it will use the page content item as the datasource.

I believe you need to use something like `RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item` when calling @Html.Sitecore().Rendering in order to pass the data source you have configured in Sitecore into your rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a rendering as dynamic rendering or static rendering.

If you are using rendering as static rendering then you will also need to define data source statically like in your example.

@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("/sitecore/layout/renderings/jobs/footercontent", new {DataSource = "/sitecore/content/Global/Footer"})

But if you want to supply data source through datasource field then you will also need to give placeholder name in other field and use the rendering dynamically like.
@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("MyPlaceholder")